# How to dynamic call property on javascript object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hallo all.
I got a javascript object with some propeties let's say

```
function Animal() {
this.id;
this.name;
```

I need to call id function in a dynamic way to get and set its value: something like this

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
var propertyName = "id";
animal.+propertyName = "name";
```

Is there an elegant way to do it? With jQuery?

Kind regards

Massimo

Comment: Soon people will think javascript is a module in jQuery

Comment: @Massimo Ugues: not as "read", as "answered".  If an answer helped you find the solution then to the left of that answer (beneath the vote count) is a tick/check mark outline.  If you hover over this, it will turn green and clicking it will mark that answer as the correct one.  Now you have over 15 rep, you can also up-vote any answers that helped towards finding a solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apart from object syntax, in JavaScript you can also use an array-like syntax to query object properties. So in your case:

```
function Animal() { this.id; this.name };
Animal animal = new Animal();
animal.id = "testId";

var propertyName = "id";
alert(animal[propertyName]); // this should alert the value "testId";
```

Here's an article with more details: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Answer (score 3):

No jQuery needed for this.  You need to use square brackets:

```
animal[propertyName] = "name";
```