# Dynamic filtering from external function with Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable

I need to filter using dynamic parameters from a form post. But I dont know how to send the parmeters with a dynamic generated name... see code below hope it explains my problem.

```
$('#kt_search').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var frm_data = $('#searchFrom').serializeArray();
$.each(frm_data, function(key, val) {

myData.comercial    = 23; //THIS WORKS

myData.val.name     = val.value; // THIS IS INCORRECT
});

table.table().draw();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamic call property on javascript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559159/how-to-dynamic-call-property-on-javascript-object-with-jquery)

Comment: yes was duplicate . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `val.name` holds the name of the property, you can access the dynamic property like so:

`myData[val.name]`

So, to set the value:

`myData[val.name] = val.value;`

Here is a fiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/o98ykn72/4/

Comment: myData[val.name] = val.value; in console.log this shows the parameters with the value but how to I get the value in the posted file?

Comment: here is my console.log `cliente: ""
comercial: "24"
end: ""
hora: ""
orderid: ""
produccion: ""
start: ""
titulo: ""`

Comment: so in the destination php file I would use `$post_comercial = $_REQUEST["comercial"];
$post_estado = $_REQUEST["estado"];` but its not working what am I missing

Comment: when a field is empty I get an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at _fnAjaxUpdateDraw (datatables.bundle.js:4126)`

Comment: @vance = seems like you have several other issues going on, and you may need to work through them one by one.  The answer I've posted above should resolve the question in your post.

Comment: I found the problem :) I was sending a field name in the form called start and end.. and was getting in conflict with the datatable scripts. it seems to be working fine now. Thanks Devlin.